# Passing Twig Variable into Template from Include?

Tags: templating

I'm trying to pass a variable value from an include into a template file.  The variable is imageRatio. Within this include file I have the logic which sets the right image ratio. My goal with this is to have one place to set the logic which I can reuse in different templates - I'm trying to keep the code DRY.

When I do the below get an error saying Variable "imageRatio" does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

**The Main Template**

```
{# The Image Ratio include #}
{% include '_includes/builders/images/imageVariants' %}

{# Create an Image Variant #}
{% set optimizedImages = block.image.one()[imageRatio] %}
{% include '_includes/builders/images/imageOptimize' %}
```

**Image Ratio Include**

```
{# Define Image Varient #}
{% if block.imageRatio == 'thumb' %}
    {% set imageRatio = 'imageVariantsThumb' %}
{% elseif block.imageRatio == '16by9' %}
    {% set imageRatio = 'imageVariants16by9' %}
{% elseif block.imageRatio == '3by2' %}
    {% set imageRatio = 'imageVariants3by2' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using macro (and `switch` tag instead of `if`).

```
{% macro ratio(block) %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% switch block.imageRatio %}
        {% case "thumb" %}
            imageVariantsThumb
        {% case "16by9" %}
            imageVariants16by9
        {% case "3by2" %}
            imageVariants3by2
    {% endswitch %}
{% endspaceless %}    
{% endmacro %}
```

Macro would be used like this:

```
{% import 'macro' as macroRatio %}
{% set imageRatio = macroRatio.ratio(block)|trim %}
```

Comment: Ah ok so when I reference {% set optimizedImages = block.image.one()[ratio] %} I get an error that says 'illegal offset type'. Apparently, this happens when attempting to access an array index using an object. How do I amend?

Comment: Actually doing {{ dump(ratio) }} I get the following... object(Twig_Markup)#1692 (2) { ["content":"Twig_Markup":private]=> string(17) "imageVariants3by2" ["charset":"Twig_Markup":private]=> string(5) "UTF-8" }   - Is there aw way to filter this?

Comment: Figured it out needed to add |trim like so: {% set ratio = m.ratio(block) %}

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details on include for twig here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

The short answer being

```
{# template.html will have access to the variables from the current context and the additional ones provided #}
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}

{% set vars = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
{% include 'template.html' with vars %}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to pass the variables the other way round - not into the include but from it.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question.  Sounds like you might want to look into macros instead though: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html

Comment: Right - I'm trying to find some documentation examples of macros that use field values but can't seem to find anything. Are you sure this would be a macro?